# Mapbox Static API: fit markers to map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I was wondering if there is an easy way to fit all the markers one the created image of MapBox static api?

I mean something that does the same as

```
map.fitBounds()
```

in the non static version?

Answer (score 1):

Static Maps only have a center and image size but you can create a static image that fits your markers' extent with the geo-viewport plugin:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/static-map-from-geojson-with-geo-viewport/